# DSLCalendarView data handling and current date

Tags: ios

I want to make a appointment app where user can select a single date or date range to book an appointment.For that I am using DSLCalenadarView this is working fine as per my requirement but the problem it I want to show the current date to be auto selected,secondly am unable to find how the data handling works because I wanted to store the select date but didn't find any  perfect solution for it.

Can one please help me to integrate this.

Answer (score 8):

Find and open `DSLCalendarDayView.m` now look for thie method, `drawBackground`

```
- (void)drawBackground {
if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected) {

            NSUInteger flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
            NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

            NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[self.day date]];
            NSDateComponents *componentsOfToday = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

            NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
            NSDate *dateToday = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsOfToday];

            if (self.isInCurrentMonth) {
                    if ([date isEqualToDate:dateToday]) {
                            [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill]; //from now current day is colored
                    }
                    else {
                            [[UIColor colorWithWhite:245.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
                    }
            }
            else {
                    if ([date isEqualToDate:dateToday]) {
                            [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill]; //even if it is not current month, current day is colored
                    }
                    else {
                            [[UIColor colorWithWhite:225.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
                    }
            }
            UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}
else {
    switch (self.selectionState) {
        case DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected:
            break;

        case DSLCalendarDayViewStartOfSelection:
            [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-left"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
            break;

        case DSLCalendarDayViewEndOfSelection:
            [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-right"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
            break;

        case DSLCalendarDayViewWithinSelection:
            [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-middle"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
            break;

        case DSLCalendarDayViewWholeSelection:
            [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use setSelectedRange to do that. Here is the snippet to auto select current date.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDateComponents *components    = [calendar components:(NSCalendarCalendarUnit |
                                      NSYearCalendarUnit     |
                                      NSMonthCalendarUnit    |
                                      NSDayCalendarUnit      |
                                      NSHourCalendarUnit     |
                                      NSMinuteCalendarUnit   |
                                      NSWeekdayCalendarUnit  |
                                      NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
DSLCalendarRange *range = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc]initWithStartDay:components endDay:components];    
[self.calendarView setSelectedRange:range];
```